# find another API instead of google map API

Tags: api, dictionary, geolocation, street-address

I'm developing an application which use map. I'm trying to avoide google API (because their request time are limited). 
I want something complete free but can provide feature like geocoding, reserve-geo, find nearest place ...
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/maps/osm-reverse-geocoder.html#findNearbyStreetsOSM)?  They are using googlemaps as well as openstreetmap for the forward and reverse searches.  I know openstreetmap can handle everything that you are asking for.